# php login page. Which is more effective 'switch statement' or 'function redirect'

Tags: php, redirect, switch-statement

I have created a php login page where the user will be directed to their unique landing page upon logging in. At the moment, the user.id and filename.php, this information is stored in a MYSQL database.

The redirect function is below.

```
/* Redirect browser */
header('Location: ' . $page_id);
/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
}
```

Is it better to use this or a switch statement, similar to this post: redirect users to different pages based on role php??

The codes work but both options seem to do the same job, i was wondering which is better? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Comparing between `switch` and `function` is like comparing bananas and apples.

Both do different jobs.

1. Functions are useful when you need reusable code (used at least 2
   times).
2. Switch cases are four times faster than `if else` but, you
   cannot compare them with `function`. In case, you can add more cases                required which is obvious more simple than adding an `if else` condition.

Comment: so in this situation I believe that using a redirect function will be easier, with the user id information stored in a database. The next stage I'm working towards is to have some code on each file that would validate the user, i.e. to ensure that no one can access the other person's data. Does that an appropriate use for function redirect.

Comment: i know that this should go in a separate post, but I'm a bit stuck on how to validate the php file. I have created a column called 'role' in my database, and numbered the 3 users as 1,2,3. I now want to say role=1 display this data... but i don't know how to write this. I have tried an if statement but ended up with a white screen.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the way you want to validate data. you must be sure that no user can access other user info , if you go for a switch make sure that when data gets there you have all the validations completed.

Of course that if you have some sort of method to get the page for a user is better to just redirect because if you have like 100 users the switch approach would be hard to read and difficult to maintain.